# How to updating parentID on Attachments Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Initially I have a task of moving Attachments from one SF to another SF, but for the parentID on which I have to associate Attachments are not there with me. So what I have done is, created test records in the Objects to load Attachment temporarily to them and after I got the ID's of the records on which I have to associate Attachment, I'll update them later.

But the problem is when I am updating the Attachments, It doesn't show to map "parentID" in that. I have read somewhere that When we insert Attachments its "parentID" becomes read-only after insertion, I have loaded around 6GB data in my test records as per their associated Objects. How can I do this?

Comment: Is there any permission required from the Salesforce End to enable the 'parentID' field as editable during Attachment Update operation ?

thanks
chirag

Comment: you might try http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok...I am trying there also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it.  As you specified in your post, ParentId becomes a read-only field after initial insertion, as is true of any master-detail link field.  Your only option is to clone the attachment to a new attachment with the new ParentId and then destroy the original.

Comment: Doing the same at present. Thanks